# Reference Request to help Parse Topology Exercise on Extending Maps with Codomains $S^n$ and $\mathbb{E}^{n+1}$

Tags: general-topology

I'm working on a problem in Armstrong's *Basic Topology* and have hit a wall. Exercise 35 on page 41 reads:

> Given a map $f : X \to \mathbb{E}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ find a map $g: X \to S^n$ which agrees with $f$ on the set $f^{-1}(S^n)$.

My hunch is that this is an extension problem. In any case, I guess I've missed the discussion in the text about these codomains, and I'm unclear about how the spaces $\mathbb{E}^{n+1}$ and $S^{n}$ relate to one another. In fact, I'm really not certain what's being asked.

Can anyone direct me to a good source to read up on these spaces and the kinds of maps that behave nicely between them?

This is a homework question, so please no direct answers. Hints that point me to the heart of the material, however, are certainly appreciated.

Comment: Normalize the values of $f$?

Comment: $S^n$ is a "special subset" of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$.